# Announcement VS Newsfeed: what is better for internal corporate news?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, newsfeed

I would like to know what you guys are using for internal news between announcements and newsfeed. With **hashtags** and **mentions** being activated in SP2013, it seems to me like either would work, but I'd like to know how you guys are using them. Setting up our intranet, I want to make sure that our employees don't get confused and I think it might be if we use both content types. Thoughts?

Comment: Since you tagged this with Sharepoint Online, I would say Announcements currently, as they are going to be removing Newsfeed in favor of Yammer.

Comment: Thank you!! You just saved me tons of time; this would have been a bad surprise